# Conformal map $\mathbb{D} \rightarrow |\Im(z)| < 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to construct a conformal map which takes the unit disk to the infinite strip $|\Im(z)| < 1$.

My thought process is to take the unit disk to the half plane, then to an infinite strip using the logarithm, and finally scale/translate as necessary.

More explicitly I am considering the composition of maps:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\log(z)\circ\frac{1-z}{1+z} = \frac{2}{\pi}\log\Big(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\Big).$$
This will be an infinite strip with $0 < \Im(z) < 2$ and so I translate my map by $-1$:
$$f(z) = \frac{2}{\pi}\log\Big(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\Big) - 1.$$

Is this correct and is the above map a valid conformal map between these two domains?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *almost* correct. The imaginary part of the principal branch of the logarithm in the right half-plane is in the range $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, so that
$$
f(z) =  \frac{2}{\pi}\log\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)
$$
is already the conformal map onto the strip $\{ \operatorname{Im}(z) < 1 \}$. The additional translation by $-1$ is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! In the text I am using (Stein) it claims the upper half plane is mapped to the infinite strip $0 \leq \Im(z) < \pi$, this is why I translated the function after scaling it. Is this mapping incorrect?

Comment: @CBBAM: I do not have that book. But $z \mapsto \frac{1-z}{1+z}$ maps the unit disk to the *right* half-plane, not to the upper half-plane. Therefore the argument of $ \frac{1-z}{1+z}$ varies between $-\pi/2$ and $+\pi/2$.

Comment: Ah I see now, after reading your comment and comparing formulas it seems I am missing an $i$ which explains it. I should also be shifting by $i$ not 1. That is, I believe I should instead have $f(z) = \frac{2}{\pi}\log\Big(i\frac{1-z}{1+z}\Big) - i$. This is equivalent to the conformal map you provided. Thanks again!